# 'Enter' detection for text mining

Tags: java, onclick, jtable

I'm in project doing a text mining. it's needed that my program also tokenize when the text using Enter in his/her document (/br if in HTML). Now my program only can detect 'space'. How to do it?
this is my code:

```
private ArrayList tokenize(String inp) {
        ArrayList<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] split = inp.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            if (!split[i].isEmpty()) {
                out.add(split[i]);
            }
        }
        return out;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use a simple regular expression to do what you want:

```
String input = "Line of text \nAnother line<br><br><br />html<br />line";
String [] parts = input.split("\\s+|(<br>|<br\\s*/>)+");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(parts));
```

It can also replace multiple whitespaces/breaklines in a row. Regular expressions can work really well for this kind of tasks.

Output:

> [Line, of, text, Another, line, html, line]

**Explanation**: `\s` is short for all whitespaces (space, tab, newline). `\s+` means 1 or more whitespaces. `<br>|<br\\s*/>` means `<br>` or `<br/>` or `<br />` or `<br     />`. They are in a group: `(<br>|<br\\s*/>)`, so we can use `+` to identify one or more of them.

The whole stuff together: one or more whitespace characters or one or more of the different versions of `<br>`.

So your tokenize method could look like this (use generics, if you use java 1.5 or later):

```
private List<String> tokenize(String inp) {
    List<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] split = inp.split("\\s+|(<br>|<br\\s*/>)+");

    for (String s : split) {
        if (!s.isEmpty()) {
            out.add(s);
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure splitting at the enters isn't already working? Because with this:

```
String s = "Hi b\nb bye";
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println();

String [] ss = s.split(" ");

for(String s2 : ss)
{
    System.out.println(s2);
}
```

This is my output:

```
Hi b
b bye

Hi
b
b
bye
```

As you can see, the string was split both at the spaces, and at the new line (even though a space was the only regex). However, if this isn't working for you, you could just cycle through the String array and and call `String.split("\n")`. Then you can just add the new split strings to an ArrayList.